# How to only override DECIMAL_SEPARATOR in django while keeping localization intact?

Tags: django, localization

Django's localization is fine. Handy to get translated days and months and proper date formatting.

My problem is that, in the Dutch locale, a comma is used to separate decimals (so: `12,45` instead of `12.45`). Theoretically, this is the right choice. In practice, however, almost everyone uses a dot as decimal separator. At least our customers do.

So: I *do* want django's localization, but I want to adjust only `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR`. Problem: localization takes preference over simply setting `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'` in my settings file.

I could add a format directory and use [FORMAT_MODULE_PATH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#format-module-path), but I dislike having to copy/paste such a directory into all of my django projects.

So: am I missing something? Is there a better way?

(Small addition: the most safe would be to *accept* either dot or comma, as virtually nobody types in thousand separators by hand.)

Comment: Do you need that only for templates? if yes then you can control localization in it directly:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/formatting/#controlling-localization-in-templates

Comment: No, I also need it in the django admin.

Comment: what about writing a simple middleware layer (sounds big but it is not: one class  and one method should be enough) that overwrites the DECIMAL_SEPARATOR after the locale middleware does. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/  and  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/middleware/

Comment: The locale middleware only sets the language/locale to be used, it doesn't itself do any translation/formatting.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? An update after 6 years would be great, as I have the exact same issue

Comment: It may sound silly, but you shouldn't set for what the majority does, but for what is correct. I have the exact... but reversed problem: Django formats some thousand separators as commas, even if the ISO standard is space – regardless the language. So searching for the same solution for the opposite reason!

Answer (score -1):

*Example: xxx = 123456*

If you want commas:

```
def commaxxx(self):
    return f"{self.xxx:,}"
```

If you want dots:

```
def dotxxx(self):
    comma = f"{self.xxx:,}"
    dot= comma.replace(',', '.')
    return dot
```