# Use different decimal separators for frontend validation in Django Admin interface

Tags: python, django

I looked through every single similar question on stackoverflow and tried nearly everything.
It seems easy to do: I just want to allow `,` as decimal separator for a `FloatField` in the Django admin interface. At the moment, it depends on the localization, but I always want to allow it. It would even be ok for me, if it's just a `TextInput`, but I need `,` to work. Setting `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` in settings.py does not work.

My question is similar to this 6 year old, unanswered one: [How to only override DECIMAL_SEPARATOR in django while keeping localization intact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430397/how-to-only-override-decimal-separator-in-django-while-keeping-localization-inta?rq=1)

I managed to use the `TextInput` widget for FloatFields like this:

```py
class ExampleAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key, value in self.fields.items():
            if isinstance(value, FloatField):
                self.fields[key].widget = TextInput()
```

The widget works, but an input like `1,23` leads to an error message `Enter a number`. I'd have to implement my own, custom FloatField that overrides the sanitizing in `to_python` to allow for differenct decimal separators, but then I'd still need a different widget. This seems awfully complicated, is there a better way?
If not, how can I change the frontend validation in the widget to ignore localization and use my own regex pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch the `to_python` method, or use a custom form field class that overrides that method.

One-liner answer:

```py
self.fields[key].to_python = lambda v: self.fields[key].__class__.to_python(self.fields[key], '.'.join(v.rsplit(',', 1)) if len(v.rsplit(',', 1)[-1]) < 3 else v)
```

As a wrapper function:

```py
self.fields[key].to_python = allow_comma_decimal_separator(self.fields[key].to_python)
```

```py
def allow_comma_decimal_separator(old_to_python):
    def to_python(value):
        if ',' in value:
            lvalue, decimals = value.rsplit(',', 1)
            if len(decimals) < 3:
                value = '.'.join((lvalue, decimals))
        return old_to_python(value)
    return to_python
```

i.e. If a comma is in the value, and the substring after the rightmost comma has a length of less than 3 (so we assume it's not a thousand separator), then we replace that comma with a period by joining the substring before and after with a period.

## For explicit fields using a reusable form field class

This would be considered less "hacky".

```py
class AllowCommaDecimalSeparatorFloatField(forms.FloatField):

    def to_python(self, value):
        if ',' in value:
            lvalue, decimals = value.rsplit(',', 1)
            if len(decimals) < 3:
                value = '.'.join((lvalue, decimals))
        return super().to_python(value)
```

In your form's `Meta` class:

```py
field_classes = {
    'myfield': AllowCommaDecimalSeparatorFloatField,
}
```

## For all FloatFields

To affect all `FloatField` instances (not instantiated yet), place this at the top of your module:

```py
old_to_python = forms.FloatField.to_python


def to_python(self, value):
    if ',' in value:
        lvalue, decimals = value.rsplit(',', 1)
        if len(decimals) < 3:
            value = '.'.join((lvalue, decimals))
    return old_to_python(self, value)


forms.FloatField.to_python = to_python
```